# Failure delivering result ResultInfo when trying to choose an image

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to make an application for my final year project.

I have created this activity which has - upload and choose buttons.

Found where the problem occurs - in my onActivityResult function on the highlighted line :

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode, data);

     if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK
        && data != null && data.getData() != null){

        mImageUri = data.getData();
```

Picasso.with(this).load(mImageUri).into(mImageView);

```
    }

}
```

There was no information that could help me on the internet.

**I am getting these errors when choosing an image from gallery along with the application crash**:

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:25 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.example.user.alphaver/com.example.alphaver.ProfileActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4845)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4886)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.
    at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:618)
    at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:601)
    at com.example.alphaver.ProfileActivity.onActivityResult(ProfileActivity.java:130)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8110)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4838)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4886) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

also the file choosing function:

```
private void openFileChooser(){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}
```

I am looking to solve the problem of crashing, I need to choose the image and display it on my ImageView.

**

> Update: Solution - update firebase implementations

**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out with this i have created demo for you to understand better :

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSelectPhoto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select Photo" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity :

```
  import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
  import java.io.File;
  import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
  import java.io.FileOutputStream;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.app.AlertDialog;
 import android.content.DialogInterface;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
 import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.os.Environment;
 import android.provider.MediaStore;
 import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.example.takeimage.R;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private int REQUEST_CAMERA = 0, SELECT_FILE = 1;
private Button btnSelect;
private ImageView ivImage;
private String userChoosenTask;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnSelect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSelectPhoto);
    btnSelect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            selectImage();
        }
    });
    ivImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case Utility.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if(userChoosenTask.equals("Take Photo"))
                    cameraIntent();
                else if(userChoosenTask.equals("Choose from Library"))
                    galleryIntent();
            } else {
                //code for deny
            }
            break;
    }
}

private void selectImage() {
    final CharSequence[] items = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Library",
            "Cancel" };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            boolean result=Utility.checkPermission(MainActivity.this);

            if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                userChoosenTask ="Take Photo";
                if(result)
                    cameraIntent();

            } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                userChoosenTask ="Choose from Library";
                if(result)
                    galleryIntent();

            } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}

private void galleryIntent()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);//
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),SELECT_FILE);
}

private void cameraIntent()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE)
            onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
        else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
            onCaptureImageResult(data);
    }
}

private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
    Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);

    File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

    FileOutputStream fo;
    try {
        destination.createNewFile();
        fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ivImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {

    Bitmap bm=null;
    if (data != null) {
        try {
            bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    ivImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
}

}
```

Utility.java //create this class for runtime permission

```
   import android.Manifest;
 import android.annotation.TargetApi;
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.DialogInterface;
 import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
 import android.os.Build;
 import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;

public class Utility {
public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 123;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
public static boolean checkPermission(final Context context)
{
    int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if(currentAPIVersion>=android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
                alertBuilder.setMessage("External storage permission is necessary");
                alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
                alert.show();

            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: check data!=null condition also after camera request also i believe not missing run time permisstion?

Comment: does CAMERA_REQUEST = 1? if yes then it also doesn't work. to your question idk what does that mean

Comment: Are you asking to runtime permission or not?

Comment: I dont know, sorry for not being dum, I have copied some codes from the internet, this is the full code of mine - https://pastebin.com/u9NtdqDV

Comment: yes got it edited code is about run time permission  which  must require  after android  6.0

Comment: so i have to add the code you posted? and CAMERA_REQUEST = 1?

Comment: can you just put your entire  code of activity  so i can directly  make changes  on that.?

Comment: Sorry for not updating, it fixed my problem thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to allow your app to have access to the file system on android

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and try to provide additional context with your answer to make it more helpful.